# c# "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

hello i have a problem with getting exception of "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=LIRON-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MatokMmagnet.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (m_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            m_cmd = new SqlCommand();
            m_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            m_cmd.Connection = m_sqlConnection;

            m_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", customer.id);
            m_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", customer.FirstName);
            m_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", customer.LastName);
            m_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", customer.Password);
            m_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (id, FirstName, LastName, Password)VALUES (@id, @FirstName, @LastName, @Password)";
            try
            {
                m_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                m_sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you not understand from the error message?

Comment: You don't open connection and want to execute query? Open it (m_sqlConnection.Open()) before execute query. Besides you haven't close because you use using block which close connection.

Comment: Are you *sure* that you want to embed your connection string in your code like that. What if you need to change it? You'll have to go to many places to update it. That's no good!

Comment: Now my connection string is in the properties. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says you must open the connection before executing the query like this :

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=LIRON-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MatokMmagnet.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    using (m_sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {`
        m_sqlConnection.open();
        //....
    }
}
```